# Why isn't reference counting working in my SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I read that `SQLiteDatabase` uses reference counting to manage two threads querying the same database at the same time, but it isn't working for me.

- Both my threads get the `SQLiteDatabase` object by calling `getWriteableDatabase()` on the same instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
- Both threads run their queries simultaneously with `SQLiteDatabase.query()`.
- I'm not using transactions.
- At the end of each query, the respective thread calls `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()`
- After the first thread closes the DB, the second throws this exception when it calls `SQLiteDatabase.query()`:

  > java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
  >   object: SQLiteDatabase:
  >   /data/user/0/com.comet.android.TypeSmart/databases/en.dic

I also tried calling `SQLiteDatabase.close()` instead of `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()` but it didn't help. :(

Isn't reference counting supposed to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

As to what nfrolov said:

> Android already implements the reference counting internally. Basically, whenever you do anything with SQLiteDatabase, it increments a counter, and when you’re done, it decrements it. **When all operations are done, DB just closes itself**. I saw absolutely no reason to second-guess this system. Just don’t close the DB. You have to close cursors though.

*reference: https://nfrolov.wordpress.com/2014/08/16/android-sqlitedatabase-locking-and-multi-threading/*

But not closing the database might result into:

```
Leak found
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
```

There is a solution where you will implement an `AtomicInteger` in which you will count how many times you've open the database and then decrement it when you are about to close, when it reaches 0, that's the time you're going to close it.

```
public class DatabaseManager {

private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

private static DatabaseManager instance;
private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseManager();
        mDatabaseHelper = helper;
    }
}

public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(DatabaseManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
    }

    return instance;
}

public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    if(mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
        // Opening new database
        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return mDatabase;
}

public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
    if(mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        // Closing database
        mDatabase.close();

    }
}
}
```

According to Dmytro Danylyk:

> Every time you need database you should call openDatabase() method of DatabaseManager class. Inside this method we have a counter, which indicates how many times database is opened. If it equals to one, it means we need to create new database. If not, database is already created.
>
> The same happens in closeDatabase() method. Every time we call this method, counter is decreased; whenever it goes to zero, we are closing database.

*Full example reference: https://blog.lemberg.co.uk/concurrent-database-access*

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it didn't help. Reference counting isn't happening automatically like nfrolov (and the Android docs) say, and Dmytro Danylyk implemented his own reference counting which seems redundant to me if SQLiteDatabase already implements it (supposedly).